# How to share video to WeChat from my app?

Tags: android, android-sharing, wechat

I want to share my video to other apps. Some of them like Instargam, Skype receive it successfully, but others ( WeChat, Line ) show "Unresolved error". I share like that:

```
 val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getString(R.string.provider), File(filePath))
 val shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
                .setType(context.contentResolver.getType(fileUri))
                .setStream(fileUri)
                .intent
```

So the bottle neck is MIME-type, I use this code for auto setting it, and it sets "video/mp4". But apps named above don't recognize this scheme.

Did anyone faced to such problem? Is it possible to solve it?

*Thanks everyone for answers in advance!*